# Determine whether Guile is running interactively

Tags: scheme, guile

How to test whether Guile running interactively?

The purpose is the following: implement an exception handler such that, if not running interactively, exceptions should print a message and exit Guile, otherwise they should print a message and do nothing (i.e. return to the REPL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way but I have one suggestion. in your .guile define a variable `*interactive*` to `#t` in the guile module via e.g.

```
(module-define! (resolve-module '(guile)) '*interactive* #t)
```

As far as I know .guile is executed exactly when guile is interactive and not when run as a program.

then you can define the following check

```
(define (interactive?) (module-defined? (resolve-module '(guile)) '*interactive*)
```